# "für" plus adjective?

Tags: preposition, grammar-identification

Is it possible for "für" to be followed by an adjective like the sentence below. I find it strange as so far I have only seen "dafür" or "für + Noun". "Für" can be somewhat translated into english as "for", and "for" is never followed by an adjective...

- Ich halte es **für richtig**, dass er absagt.

Comment: @guidot I would expect an explanation of why this is possible in an answer. Also, no, it shouldn't be "consider as". I would translate as "I consider it right that he cancelled."

Comment: @Roland: You may want to reconsider this [meta question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1696), especially the section starting "Nevertheless", stating your comments should be deleted.

Comment: @Roland -- I would say that "to consider as" is closer *betrachten*, while this construction is more like "to take for". There is considerable overlap but "consider" implies that the person is aware that the belief is just an opinion: "I consider you to be a good painter." Meanwhile "to take for" implies that the belief is as fact, especially when it is mistaken somehow: "Sorry I hit you; I took you for an intruder." My understanding is that the situation is about the same with *betrachten* and *für __ nehmen*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *halten* in combination with *für* forms a kind of "Phrasal verb", in other words the combination takes on a different meaning than the meaning of the two words together would imply. (With a separable verb, in contrast, the preposition does not have to be part of a prepositional phase. I don't know the official name for these things, but "Phrasal verb" seems descriptive.) There are are a number of them, for example *einladen* with *auf* -- "treat to", *richten* with *auf* -- "point at", *sehen* with *nach* -- "see about". In this case *halten* with *für* means "take for", as in believing something is something else. For example *Hält er mich für einen Trottel?* -- "Does he take me for a fool?" (from Wiktionary). You can also put an adjective in place of the something else to get something like your example: *Ich halte es für richtig ...* -- "I take it as right ..." So it's the unusual circumstance of this one verb plus preposition combination which happens to allow a adjective to take the place of one of the nouns that make the *für* + adjective possible here; it doesn't normally occur.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible, see [DWDS](http://dwds.de/wb/halten#d-1-12).

Keep in mind, that *für* can't be considered separately, but is part of the construction *jemanden/etwas für etwas halten* (Engl. *consider*)